# How to store an InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: interpolation, persistence

Assume I have obtained an `InterpolatingFunction`, say, as the result of solving of a differential equation, say, this one:

```
 sol = First[
  NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y], 
      t] == 0.075  (D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y]) - 
      u[t, x, y] (2 D[u[t, x, y], x] -  D[u[t, x, y], y]), 
    u[0, x, y] == Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], u[t, -4, y] == u[t, 4, y], 
    u[t, x, -4] == u[t, x, 4]}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]]
```

(it is simply an example taken from a tutorial, just to have something to discuss).

I would like to store this function in the notebook, such that I can get this interpolating function upon reopening of the notebook without solving this equation once more.

Indeed, a real-world equation may be much more complex and may require much more time, than this one. A further work with the solution without resolving the equation would be of advantage.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just `DumpSave` the symbol, `Get` where needed?

Comment: Thank you, this works. Why should not you formulate this as a regular answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about adding these lines of code below?

```
u /. %;
FullForm @ %
```

Then saving the notebook. Once reopened, the `FullForm` will be present as an output cell and you can type in `u =` right in front of that cell and input that.

**UPDATE**

Screenshot of what happens after I close the notebook, then `ClearAll[sol, u]`, then reopen it again and carry out my suggested steps. Clicking "show all" isn't necessary.

[image: notebook]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately when I do this I get a "Large output" message, and after I press the button "Show all" the hang-up follows.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I actually didn't even bother pressing "Show all". Doing all the other steps I've listed, I then simply typed `Plot3D[u[1,x,y],{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4}] and everything plotted fine.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I have updated my answer to demonstrate better.

Comment: BTW, when I click "Show all" my machine does take a few moments to think, but then outputs everything gracefully.

Comment: Right, if I do not press "Show all", it works, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, though I have to concede, ciao's comment is the cleaner and more programmatic way of doing this.

Comment: LLlAMnYP Yes, I like ciao's approach also. One cannot accept two answers though. Besides, I more readily keep all the data within the same notebook in a separate InitializationCell, such that I could initialize all without thinking much of where did I store all that.  This is private taste, however.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`LocalSymbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalSymbol.html) (version 10.2 and above) to store the result in the local file system for retrieval in any notebook even after a kernel restart. Add the following:

```
LocalSymbol["MySolution"] = sol;
```

`"MySolution"` can be any string.  Now the value of `sol` is stored in the file system.  To retrieve its value later use:

```
LocalSymbol["MySolution"]
```

The value of `sol` is returned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is quite neat.

Comment: @Edmund Thank you. Do I understand correctly that the function is saved somewhere in the actual notebook?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch No, it is not stored in the notebook but in the directory returned by `$LocalSymbolBase`. Because it is in a directory then any notebook can access it even after restarting Mathematica.